Meaning of ことを受ける
This comes from a new Reuters JP article I read today about Netanyahu's responses to Iran's missile/drone launchings:
[エルサレム １４日 ロイター] - イスラエルのネタニヤフ首相は１４日、イランが発射した３００超のドローン（無人機）とミサイルのほぼ全てを撃墜したと国軍が発表したことを受け、勝利を収めると表明した。
DeepL: "[Jerusalem, April 14 (Reuters) - Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu declared victory on Thursday after the national army announced that it had shot down nearly all of the more than 300 drones and missiles fired by Iran."
I assume the "after" part refers to ことを受ける, and if I were to infer the meaning I would translate it as so:
"Receiving that/the fact that the national army announced that they had shot down nearly all of the missiles and drones..."
I get that the こと is nominalizing 発表した, but what this is really pointing to is something like "in response to the national army announcing that...", which there are other ways to do, so I am not sure why this structure is being used or what nuance it adds. In addition, I really don't think we use the word "receive" like this in English, so I wonder if this adds any implications about the breath of 受ける in contrast to the English counterpart.

As you say, this is about someone's responses. In order to respond, you need to first get something. 〜を受け（て） is used when you make some decision in response to some development in the situation you didn't (directly) cause. You "received" that development in the situation and now you are taking it into your decision about your next move.
A direct translation of "after," such as 発表してから and 発表した後に, would put unnecessary emphasis on the order of the two events.
